# Passportjs Google Authentication Callback Error

Tags: passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I am running into a `500 Internal Server` server error when my callback route is called for a Google login and I'm not sure what part of my code is causing the issue. As you can see from my terminal results, it is passing the if statement condition and triggering the cb function which is responding and outputting `[object SequelizeInstance:external_account]`. Could the output be the incorrect value? I'm not exactly sure what value should be getting accepted by the call.

**Console Log:**

```
If statement was true externalId and Email present
GET /auth/google/callback?code=4/mvFTIURH5P0ACQFwZobC04-ftehalfdf4454 500 434.737 ms - 44
[object SequelizeInstance:external_account]
```

**PassportJS setup:**

```
/*====  Google Configuration  ====*/

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: 'client-id',
    clientSecret: 'client-secret',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        var user;
        models.User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: profile.emails[0].value
            }
        }).then(function(_user){
            user = _user;
            return models.ExternalAccount.findOne({
                where: {
                    externalSourceId: profile.id
                }
            }).then(function(externalAccount, err){
                if(user && externalAccount){
                console.log("If statement was true externalId and Email present");
                return cb(externalAccount, err)
            } else if (user){
                console.log("Else If statement was true Email was present, but no account Id");
                return models.ExternalAccount.create({
                    externalSource: "Google",
                    externalSourceId: externalAccount.externalSourceId,
                    userId: externalAccount.user.id
                }).then(function(){
                    return cb(externalAccount, err)
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Error');
            }
            })
        })
  }));
```

**routes:**

```
/*====  /AUTH/GOOGLE  ====*/

siteRoutes.route('/auth/google') 
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

/*====  /AUTH/GOOGLE/CALLBACK  ====*/

siteRoutes.route('/auth/google/callback') 
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
            successRedirect : '/app',
            failureRedirect : '/login',
            failureFlash: 'Invalid Google credentials.'
        }),function(req, res){
        res.redirect('/app');
    });
```

Comment: have you tried writing your code in process.nextTick???

Comment: @SuryaPurohit yes and I still receive the same error

Comment: @SuryaPurohit could it be the value that is being returned? `[object SequelizeInstance:external_account]` An object that is being sent as a response page value?

Comment: When I console log `externalAccount` I get undefined and when I console log `cb` I get `[Function: verified]`, `err` `[object SequelizeInstance:external_account]` and finally `cb(err, externalAccount)` gives me `[object SequelizeInstance:external_account]` What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Error might have been occurred from google's server if you're not using https.
Google login api only accepts the secured network using ssl.
Try with ssl. if you're still on this problem...